# Image lib - can`t reduce the quality of a image

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to reduce the quality of uploaded image. Here is my code

```
$image_config['source_image'] = 'file.jpg';
$image_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$image_config['quality']    = '30%';
$image_config['width'] = 1680;
$image_config['height'] = 1050;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $image_config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

The problem is so image has the same quality as the file.jpg etc it is not reduced.

Answer (score 2):

I face same problem and I found something in image library file.

system/libraries/image_library.php   line 455

```
if ($this->dynamic_output === FALSE)
    {
        if ($this->orig_width == $this->width AND $this->orig_height == $this->height)
        {
            if ($this->source_image != $this->new_image)
            {
                if (@copy($this->full_src_path, $this->full_dst_path))
                {
                    @chmod($this->full_dst_path, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
                }
            }

            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

This code ignore image rendering if width and height of destination image is the same as the source image. 
Remove the above code and it should works.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Nick, have you tried to display the errors?

```
if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Possible errors I can think of : not giving the correct path to the file or not having installed one of the 3 image libraries (GD/GD2, NetPBM or ImageMagick)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i had same problem, and it just return TRUE every time.

Answer (score 1):

You just need need to give Numeric value  not with "%" sign

Like  `$image_config['quality']  = '30';`

Answer (score 0):

Also check the real mime type. PNG files renamed with JPG extension cannot be reduced by quality.

```
$info = getimagesize($_filepath);
echo $info['mime'];
```